# Extjs 4: Programatically reorder tabpanel tabs

Tags: extjs

I was wondering if anyone knows how to reorder the tabs in a tabpanel programatically. I've been able to reorder them using the drag-drop plugin, but I'd also like to allow for moving tabs using keyboard shortcuts.

Unfortunately, everything I've tried has failed:

Neither:

`tabpanel.move(newindex, oldindex)`

nor

`tabpanel.items.remove(1)
tabpanel.items.insert(2)`

has worked. Even when I try to call layout updates afterwards..

`tabpanel.doComponentLayout();
tabpanel.doLayout();
tabpanel.updateLayout();`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are moving the items around, but the tabs of a tabpanel consist of two different things: An item, which is in a card layout, and a tab, which is inside a `hbox` tabbar which is a `dockedItem` at the top of the tabpanel. What you want to move is the tab, not the item:

```
tabpanel.down('tabbar').move(0,1);
```